# Mandatory capturing data before every org file is modified

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-capture

I have to create a list of documents I modified or created in a day. I use org-capture to create it. I use following org capture template to capture the data when I start working on the file

```
    ("c" "List" checkitem (file+olp+datetree"C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/personal/journal.org")
   " [ ]%T %?\n\n" :prepend t :kill-buffer t   )
```

While it does a fair job, I at times forget to capture the name of the file. 
Is it possible to pop up a capture template every time I open an org file, so that I don't forget to enlist the file I modify!

Your help is highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: How about something like?:  `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-capture)`

Comment: Though it fires the select capture template option screen, the template key fails to work further.